# callback for "ext.flutter.inspector.getRootWidgetSummaryTree"

Tags: flutter

Today when I start the flutter 2.0.x app, shows error:

```
======== Exception caught by Flutter framework =====================================================
The following _CastError was thrown during a service extension callback for "ext.flutter.inspector.getRootWidgetSummaryTree":
Null check operator used on a null value

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      WidgetInspectorService._registerObjectGroupServiceExtension.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart:793:84)
#1      WidgetInspectorService._registerObjectGroupServiceExtension.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/widget_inspector.dart:792:17)
#2      BindingBase.registerServiceExtension.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/binding.dart:597:32)
<asynchronous suspension>
====================================================================================================
```

seems flutter framework error. why did this happen? any clue about this? is it possible to fix it or avoid this eror?

Comment: I've got the same problem! Let me know if you find a solution! Thank you.

Comment: And I've got it too. when some repeating work does many time this error happens for me . But nothing got problem , so I neglect for now . It seems it is also a platform issue. So please set an Issue on flutter github.

Comment: my flutter was 2.2.3 . i updated to 2.5.2 problem fixed

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I faced the same problem (flutter 2.2.0). Looks like framework issue. Then I downgraded to Flutter 2.0.3 . Now it is working fine.

Comment: seems it does not effect the program running. I am not downgrade now.

Answer (score 3):

Same issue. I was able to get around this by unchecking "Track widget rebuilds".

Comment: You can find "Track widget rebuilds" at Flutter performance in Android Studio.

Answer (score 0):

if you did upgrade from non null safety with the dart tool migration tool. This left behind a lot of null check operators and we must to clean the code carefully to prevent those errors. I suggest that you take the time and look for that null operators and make your code much efficients making null validations for yourself.